# Laravel Call to undefined method Query\Builder

Tags: laravel

I have product Model which belongs to Shop Model.
Shop Can be Active or in Active, So I need to get products from active shops only.
So I added this method

```
public function isActiveShop(){
    return $this->where($this->shop->status,'active');
}
```

and from my controller

```
$prodcuts = Product::where('id',$rawArray)->isActiveShop()->get();
```

And I get this error

> "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isActiveShop()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes) and [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```php
public function scopeIsActiveShop($query) {
    return $query->whereHas('shop', function($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'active');
    });
}
```

Comment: That's work as I suppose but I got a new error
 Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: `$this->shop->status` looks a bit strange. Do you just mean `->where('status', 'active')`?

Comment: shop is a relation method
public function shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class);
    }

Comment: Thanks, that's works perfectly.
any reference to study that part!!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$products = (new Product())->isActiveShop()->where('id',$rawArray)->get();
```

Comment: That's work ,scope is better for solution as I think